# Long application startup time in react native ios app with firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, app-startup

Our application built with react native and it's using firebase as well.
For firebase integration, we are using the react-native-firebase package.

The android output is fine, but the ios have an unknown issue with startup time.

It takes an unusual long time, often. After some research and builds, we find out its related to the network.

For example, testing with [Browserstack](https://app-live.browserstack.com/) app testing platform, whenever we use [4G network type](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/test-real-user-conditions/simulate-network-conditions), it will take a long time to startup, but the rest of other network types is loading app under 2seconds

Another client test reported, its working fine with mobile data internet, but with fiber optic internet it takes up to 15s.

We tried many ways to find and fix the issue and failed. We tried the multiple build approaches which is the new build system and legacy build but didn't fix it.
Also, we have disabled the firebase offline feature, but it wasn't change it.